Where do I make the OAuth 2.0 code endpoint request for access tokens from AWS Cognito Hosted UI redirect
I have a /signup component with just a button that links to my congito hosted UI. Signup and login is working in terms of adding a user to the userpool and confirming email. My redirect url is https://localhost:3000/dashboard/ I only want logged in users to be able to see the dashboard.
Of course after signup or login I am being redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard?code=3db693ac-b1f4-4723-b4de-d13324392ed2 , where this code param is an oauth code to be exchanged for access tokens. Cognito does not seem to be handling this oauth code exchange automatically under the hood.
I know I am supposed to make a request with that auth code according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html to 'https://.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token. My problem is NOT how to write this reqest
My problem is getting that post request to execute and knowing where to write it. It cannot be executed/written in the /signup route because the oauth code param is only given after signup or login after clicking the hosted UI link when the url won't be /signup .
I cannot write this request in /dashboard because I cannot get to dashboard in the first place to execute it (which this problem is preventing) due to the auth code param itself in the url. I am also unsure whether to write it in a useEffect hook which is what I currently have as well as what to do with the response token after.
I am not sure how to handle it in the backend or whether that is even a valid approach because I cannot execute that post to the flask backend to make the token post because of hte reasons above. Currently I think the front end handling is the way/
My request code I need to execute is below. My AWS userpool is a no secret app client and my app is a react flask web app.
useEffect(() => {
setClientId(cognito_config['aws_user_pools_web_client_id']);

const authCodeSignUrl = 'https://waveover-dev.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token'

const handleCodeParam = () => {

    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const rawCode = urlParams.get('code');
    const authCode =  String(rawCode)

    if (authCode) {
        console.log('auuthCode is', authCode)

        axios.post(authCodeSignUrl, null, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
              },
            params: {
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                client_id: cognito_config['aws_user_pools_web_client_id'],
                // client_secret: 'xxxxx replace with your secret xxxxxx',
                code: authCode,
                redirect_uri: cognito_config['oauth']['redirectSignIn']
            }
            }).then(response => {
                    const newAccessToken = response.data.access_token;
            }).catch(error => {
                    console.log('Nae access', error);
            });
    }
};

handleCodeParam();
}, []);

I tried writing the post reqeust inside dashboard and signup components
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> 
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          {/*<Route path="/argument" component={ArgumentPage} />*/}  
          {/*<Route path="/response" component={ResponsePage} />*/}  
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;

Again my signup component is below where the button with a link to the hosted UI. I am just testing this for manual email and pw login/signup at the moment not Google signup.
return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => signUpWithGoogle('Google')}>Sign Up</button>
    </div>
);


My problem is literally understanding how to get some code in a react component /route to trigger when the url is http://localhost:3000/route?code=3db693ac-b1f4-4723-b4de-d13324392ed2 because currently that loads no resource with given url

In the authorization code flow case, the redirect url should call some server-side(backend) API. Then in the server side API, a token request(with the code) is made to get the access token.
The authorization code flow is normally regarded as the server-side flow. As the document says

authorization code grant flow doesn't show token contents directly to your users. Instead, your
app is responsible for retrieving and securely storing your user's
tokens.

In your case, you have a server-side app. It is suggested to securely store the client secret on your server. When initiating the authorization code flow, your server includes the client secret in requests made to Cognito's token endpoint to exchange the authorization code for an access token.

I'll try backend then (with boto3 etc) but I still cannot get any code whatsoever to trigger on the redirect after the hosted UI in order to retrieve the code eg
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const rawCode = urlParams.get('code');
const authCode =  String(rawCode)
Whether for a frontend req or to send the code to the backend because http://localhost:3000/dashboard?code=3db693ac-b1f4-4723-b4de-d13324392ed2 has no source on inspect
a trailing slash to redirect for http://localhost:3000/dashboard/ in console/cofig does not work either
